# my c program con't go ahead (only scanf and printf in it)

Tags: c

Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x25630a)
this is my first time use xcode and learn c.
I just want to scanf a lowercase letter and change it into an uppercase letter.
but I can't stop my program and don't know what happend now.

```
int main () {
    char ch;
    scanf("%c", &ch);
    ch = ch - 32;
    printf('%c\n', ch);
    return 0;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DPI0.jpg)

Comment: Post code as text, not a picture. You have to use `"` for the `printf` format string instead of `'`.

Comment: Please post at least your code as text here, as [mre]. Quote error messages in full, verbatim and as text directly here. If you think that the picture carries more information than that, then please point that out.

Comment: This `'%c\n'` is an *integer character constant* which you are passing as a pointer value to `printf` and this effectively random address causes a bad memory access. It should be `"%c\n"`.

Comment: Save time, enable all warnings.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main () {
    char ch;
    scanf("%c", &ch);
    ch = ch - 32;
    printf("%c\n", ch);
    return 0;
}
```

oh, this is my code. I put it here and don't need to see the picture.

I know what mistake I have,  **c can't use single quote**

thanks

Comment: C *can* use a single quote, but not for a string definition.

Answer (score 0):

Single quote are not, so you can just change them with double quote and it should work.